# recursion query in hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, recursive-query

I want to write the below query in hibernate but not getting the desired output, can anybody help me out on this?

```
with recursive FolderHierarchy as (
select
    folder_id
from
    iam.ice_folder
where
    workspace_id = 'wksc-5cc9a319-86bf-5569-beb8-76f1e9dfc886'
    and is_deleted = 0
    and folder_id = 'fldr-4935a498-322d-5efa-bf2c-790b15b0c5f4'
union
select
    f.folder_id
from
    iam.ice_folder f
join FolderHierarchy fh on
    f.parent_folder = fh.folder_id
)
select
    folder_id
from
    FolderHierarchy;
```

The code I tried is the below but its not working

```
public List<String> getAllNestedFolderIds(String folderId, String workspaceId) {
    String sqlQuery =
        "with recursive FolderHierarchy as (select folder_id from iam.ice_folder where workspace_id = :workspaceId and is_deleted = 0 and folder_id = :folderId union select f.folder_id from iam.ice_folder f join FolderHierarchy fh on f.parent_folder = fh.folder_id) select folder_id from FolderHierarchy";
    Query query =
        entityManager
            .createNativeQuery(sqlQuery)
            .setParameter(WORKSPACE_ID, workspaceId)
            .setParameter(QueryAttributes.FOLDER_ID, folderId);
    return query.getResultList();
  }
```

Comment: can you also provide some test data ? i mean some `iam.ice_folder` rows, and also expected output

Comment: @AndreiLisa folderId="flrd-reer-werwer0werwerer" and workspaceId ="wrksp-reer-werwer0werwer=er" and desired output is ["flrd-reer-werwer0werweresdf", "flrd-reer-wesdsrwerer"]

Comment: Just ditch hibernate, it's awful!. You and your team will be much happier.

Comment: Which error excatly do you get?

Comment: @SveKamenska I'm not getting any error but when I run the query directly in the database it works its giving 4 records as expected but when I put it in the code its giving empty list

Comment: Have you debug which parameters are passed to the query? Also what is the value of WORKSPACE_ID ? It should be "workspaceId"

Comment: @SveKamenska yes I've checked, and everything is correct.

Comment: Then another 2 questions: 1. Do you run query against the same DB you are checking directly? Because maybe in you settings you use another DB which is empty, for example. 2. Are you sure that list is converted correctly? By default the result is returned as type List<Object[]> not List<String>, so maybe it is not converted correctly

Comment: Are you sure you executed exactly the same query directly in the database? A recursive query is supposed to use UNION ALL,  not simple UNION.